# How do i set the dimensions of a modalDialog popup according to the dimensions of the body (just a simple table) that it displays?

Tags: java, html, popup, autoresize, showmodaldialog

How do i set the dimensions of a modalDialog popup according to the dimensions of the body that it displays?

I am displaying a small table in a popup in the form of a modalDialog called from a parent page. I need to show the popup according to the table's height, as and when the popup appears. In that way the popup won't show a blank portion of its body unoccupied by the table..right, and it'd look better. This is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `validate()` to recalculate the layout.

Comment: I suspect the OP is referring to an HTML pop-up.

Comment: as u suggested, i used this in $(document).ready on the html popup.... $(document).validate();...but it didn't work :(